# Android Notification Action - Intent Extra not working as expected

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I'm creating a `notification` with multiple actions.  I'm using `broadcast intents` to communicate that one has been pushed and take specific action.  There are 4 buttons, and I've created 4 separate intents.  Each one has the same Action string, but a different `StringExtra`.

```
Intent intNow = new Intent(mThis, MyReceiver.class).setAction(actionNotify).putExtra("button", ACT_NOW);
    Intent intEmail = new Intent(mThis, MyReceiver.class).setAction(actionNotify).putExtra("button", ACT_EMAIL);
    Intent intLater = new Intent(mThis, MyReceiver.class).setAction(actionNotify).putExtra("button", ACT_LATER);
    Intent intNever = new Intent(mThis, MyReceiver.class).setAction(actionNotify).putExtra("button", ACT_NEVER);

    Notification.Builder myRatingNotification = new Notification.Builder(mThis)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .addAction(0, mThis.getString(R.string.Rate_Act_Now), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mThis, 0, intNow, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
            .addAction(0, mThis.getString(R.string.Rate_App_Email), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mThis, 0, intEmail, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
            .addAction(0, mThis.getString(R.string.Rate_Act_Later), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mThis, 0, intLater, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
            .addAction(0, mThis.getString(R.string.Rate_Act_Never), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mThis, 0, intNever, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    Notification notification = new Notification.BigTextStyle(myRatingNotification).bigText(text).build();
    ((NotificationManager) mThis.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(notificationId, notification);
```

So the notification is created successfully.  The buttons are there.  But no matter which one I push, the extra that is passed to the `receiver` is always the last action defined.  That is, in the example above, every button returns a String Extra equal to `ACT_NEVER`.  If I reorder the `.addAction`  so intLater is last, the receiver tells me that the String Extra is equal to `ACT_LATER`, no matter which button I push.

I can't figure out why - the 4 `Intents` are completely independent of each other.  The actions specify the correct `Intent`.  What's going on?  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. you should set an icon as first parameter,not 0.
2. your current result because you use same action and same requestCode to construct a PendingIntent,so the 4 PendingIntent will be the same,and you use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`,so the last PendingIntent's extra will replace pre one.

So to solve your problem,you just need to set different `requestCode` for four `PendingIntent`,like this:

```
.addAction(0, mThis.getString(R.string.Rate_Act_Now), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mThis, 0, intNow, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
.addAction(0, mThis.getString(R.string.Rate_App_Email), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mThis, 1, intEmail, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
.addAction(0, mThis.getString(R.string.Rate_Act_Later), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mThis, 2, intLater, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
.addAction(0, mThis.getString(R.string.Rate_Act_Never), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mThis, 3, intNever, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
```

Comment: That's it!  Using a different RequestCode did the trick.  Somehow I was under the impression that RequestCode wasn't being utilized since there's not a way to access it from the called class.  Thanks!

Comment: @Scott,glad to help you,same bug occurred to me just before.

Comment: "you should set an icon as first parameter,not 0." Why, what if I don't want any icon?

Answer (score 2):

I have read documentation about `addAction()`, and quite interesting stuff is there:

- A notification in its expanded form can display up to **3 actions**
- Every action **must** have an icon

You use 0 as a Icon, and 4 actions, maybe this have some impact on behavior

Comment: The answer above (RequestCode) seems to have done the trick.  But your mention of up to 3 actions was something I'd totally missed and need to fix.  Thanks!